# Show result of 2 checkbox filters or more

Tags: php

I am trying to filter the products with checkboxes, but I can only show the value of 1 checkbox. 
If you click 2 checkboxes only show the value of the first checkbox.

This is the html:

```
<form action="busqueda.php" method="post">
  <input type="checkbox" name="especias" id="especias" <?php if($_POST[ 'especias']){ ?>checked="checked"<? } ?>>
  <span class="cbx">Especias</span><br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="sales" id="sales" <?php if($_POST[ 'sales']){ ?>checked="checked"<? }?>>
  <span class="cbx">Sales</span><br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="tes" id="tes" <?php if($_POST[ 'tes']){ ?>checked="checked"<? }?>>
  <span class="cbx">Tes e Infusiones</span> <br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="otros" id="otros" <?php if($_POST[ 'otros']){ ?>checked="checked" <? }?>>
  <span class="cbx">Otros</span> <br>
  <input type="submit" name="tipoProducto" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

And this is php:

```
  if(isset($_POST['tipoProducto'])){
    // search in all table columns
    // using concat mysql function
    if(isset($_POST['especias'])){
      $query = "SELECT nombre, usos, peso, foto, `tipo de producto` FROM `producto` WHERE `tipo de producto`='especias'";
      $search_result = filterTable($query);
    }
    else if(isset($_POST['sales'])){
      $query = "SELECT nombre, usos, peso, foto, `tipo de producto` FROM `producto` WHERE `tipo de producto`='sales'";
      $search_result = filterTable($query);
    }
    else if(isset($_POST['tes'])){
      $query = "SELECT nombre, usos, peso, foto, `tipo de producto` FROM `producto` WHERE `tipo de producto`='infusiones'";
      $search_result = filterTable($query);
    }
    else if(isset($_POST['otros'])){
      $query = "SELECT nombre, usos, peso, foto, `tipo de producto` FROM `producto` WHERE `tipo de producto`='infusiones'";
      $search_result = filterTable($query);
    }
    else if(isset($_POST['especias']) && isset($_POST['sales'])){
      $query = "SELECT nombre, usos, peso, foto, `tipo de producto` FROM `producto` WHERE `tipo de producto`='especias'";
      $query = "SELECT nombre, usos, peso, foto, `tipo de producto` FROM `producto` WHERE `tipo de producto`='sales'";
      $search_result = filterTable($query);
    }
}?>
```

Thanks, and here is the link of the testing website: http://onena.modacanela.com/productos.html

Comment: I think this `<? } ?>` is not a valid php syntax

Comment: @Fil That's perfectly valid syntax https://3v4l.org/FrJqU

Comment: I tried it, but it show an error, saying `syntax error, unexpected end of file in...` but my answer below work

Comment: thanks but the problem i think is with the php, as only so the result of 1 checkbox. and the syntax is valid.

Answer (score 0):

Here is your original code,

```
<form action="busqueda.php" method="post">
  <input type="checkbox" name="especias" id="especias" <?php if($_POST[ 'especias']){ ?>checked="checked"<? } ?>>
  <span class="cbx">Especias</span><br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="sales" id="sales" <?php if($_POST[ 'sales']){ ?>checked="checked"<? }?>>
  <span class="cbx">Sales</span><br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="tes" id="tes" <?php if($_POST[ 'tes']){ ?>checked="checked"<? }?>>
  <span class="cbx">Tes e Infusiones</span> <br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="otros" id="otros" <?php if($_POST[ 'otros']){ ?>checked="checked" <? }?>>
  <span class="cbx">Otros</span> <br>
  <input type="submit" name="tipoProducto" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

You're using `<? } ?>` in your input to close the brackets for the if condition.
Use instead `<?php } ?>`

Here the code look like,

```
<form action="busqueda.php" method="post">
  <input type="checkbox" name="especias" id="especias" <?php if(true) { ?>checked="checked"<?php } ?>>
  <span class="cbx">Especias</span><br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="sales" id="sales" <?php if(true) { ?>checked="checked"<?php }?>>
  <span class="cbx">Sales</span><br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="tes" id="tes" <?php if(true){ ?>checked="checked"<?php }?>>
  <span class="cbx">Tes e Infusiones</span> <br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="otros" id="otros" <?php if(true){ ?>checked="checked" <?php }?>>
  <span class="cbx">Otros</span> <br>
  <input type="submit" name="tipoProducto" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: Hi @Fil, thats make all the checkbox checked from the start, i want to check 2 or 3 and so the result of the 2 of then, not only the result of only the 1 checkbox. thanks